# how to stream, save and play an mp3 file in iOS

Tags: ios, streaming, avplayer

I have a list of URLs which contain mp3s, I want to stream and save them, moreover I want to play them in a the given sequence.

Answer (score 0):

AVPlayerItem *item=[AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"YOUR URL"]]];

AVPlayer *audioPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:songItem];

Important note : you have to declare AVPlayer *audioPlayer in interface only(.h file), then you can use like 
audioPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:songItem];
[audioPlayer play];

Happy coding...

Comment: does the item remains persistant?